# How to simply insert JSON string into JSON field in postgreSQL using npgsql driver

Tags: c#, json, postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to insert a json string into a json field in postgreSQL using npgsql in C#. The problem is that I receive the following error:

```
    column "column1" is of type json but expression is of type text
```

I would first like to point out that I have first tested the json strings on https://jsonlint.com/ to ensure they are valid. While not official, I have been following the tutorials on http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/. Essentially, the following should just work:

```
     string json_string = "{\"glossary\": {\"title\": \"example glossary\",\"GlossDiv\": {\"title\": \"S\",\"GlossList\": {\"GlossEntry\": {\"ID\": \"SGML\",\"SortAs\": \"SGML\",\"GlossTerm\": \"Standard Generalized Markup Language\",\"Acronym\": \"SGML\",\"Abbrev\": \"ISO 8879:1986\",\"GlossDef\": {\"para\": \"A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.\",\"GlossSeeAlso\": [\"GML\", \"XML\"]},\"GlossSee\": \"markup\"}}}}}";

    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 (column1) VALUES (@p)";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@p", json_string));
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

where table1 and column1 were created as follows:

```
    CREATE TABLE table1 (column1 json not null);
```

There are some similar posts, and I know this is a common problem, but I have yet to see a satisfactory answer to my question.

Since json_string is a valid JSON string, column1 stores json fields, and all that I have read indicates that strings map naturally to json in postgreSQL, I don't understand why I get the error:

```
    column "column1" is of type json but expression is of type text
```

Is there a simple solution to store my json string?

Comment: Did you try setting `NpgsqlDbType.Json`?

Comment: E.g. something like `new NpgsqlParameter("@p", NpgsqlDbType.Json) { Value = json_string }`?

Comment: That's interesting, there's a [documented constructor](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter.html#Npgsql_NpgsqlParameter__ctor_System_String_NpgsqlTypes_NpgsqlDbType_) with arguments `String, NpgsqlDbType`.  But it looks like [`NpgsqlDbType`](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter.html#Npgsql_NpgsqlParameter_NpgsqlDbType) is settable, so try setting it after constructing the `NpgsqlParameter` using teh current constructor.

Comment: @dbc I think that's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 (column1) VALUES (@p)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@p", NpgsqlDbType.Json) { Value = json_string });
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```